# ABD DEVICE: not found

Tags: react-native

I have an app written in react native. So far it has been great. But Now a friend of mine has some issues with his new phone nokia 5.3. The buttons has gotten really small and the layout is off. I suspect its because of the weird aspect ratio of 20:9.

Now i obviously want to correct the issue, but when i connect the phone to my macbook pro 16 it will not show up in the device manager.

I have it on the same WIFI, and USB- debugging mode is on.

My other Android phone Samsung galaxy s8 works fine, and show up in the device manager.

Ive have tried the following.

1. restarted the ABD server
2. reset the developer options on the phone
3. disconnecting the usb several times

Comment: What output does `adb devices` give you on your terminal?

Comment: List of devices attached


And then the list is empty

Answer (score 0):

Connect the device via USB and then run on the terminal

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

and open the app, this should trigger the bundler to properly work, but if it doesn't you can also set the bundle location to you local IP, just make your phone and the computer are in the same wifi and set it as `<your-local-ip>:8081`

Once that the bundler loads the full JS bundle you will get a white screen then close the app and open it again, this should work.